# string with <> around it not displaying when HTML rendered using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string

I have an MVC app.
In one of the ASPX views I have a select drop down.
Inside the select dropdown, I have a "for" loop, looping through a List within ViewData.
For each item, it creates an option in the select dropdown.

My issue is that for one or more of the items, the string value might be encompassed by "<>" characters.

However, when the page is rendered, that option is inserted into the select dropdown, but with a blank string for the value instead of "".

What do I have to do to go about rendering the "" in the dropdown's value attribute.

Here's my code:

```
    <select class="formtext" id="siteSelectDropdown" onchange="siteDropDownChange();" style="display:inline">
<%foreach (WebClientLib.Site site in ViewData["Sites"] as List<WebClientLib.Site>)
  {
      <option value="<%=site.Id %>"><%=site.Name%></option>
  }%>
```

Comment: I wonder what would happen if someone entered the string `</option></select><script src="im.in/ur/page.js">`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `<%: site.Id %>` and `<%: site.Name %>` instead of the versions with `=`. Or, if you're in .NET 3.5 or earlier, instead do `<%= Html.Encode(site.Id) %>`; the former syntax is .NET 4 shorthand for the latter.

These HTML-encode the string before outputting it, so instead of e.g. `<hello>` you would get `&lt;hello&gt;`, which is the proper way to put `<` and `>` in HTML.

You should make a habit of ALWAYS doing this, and never using `<%= stuff %>`, since as mentioned by Anon's comment, the latter leaves you open to XSS and other HTML-injection attacks. Indeed, if you properly use `HtmlString`s in your models and viewdata, you can avoid ever using the insecure version.

Comment: @Michael, how about `<%=Html.Encode(site.Name)%>`, which does the same thing as what @Domenic suggested, but has been around longer?

Comment: if you're using .net 3.5 do this: `<%= Html.Encode(site.Id) %>` - the <%: operator is shorthand introduced in 4.0.

Comment: I used Html.Encode and the value in the dropdown is still blank in the UI.
When I view source, this is the source:


 <select class="formtext" id="siteSelectDropdown" onchange="siteDropDownChange();" style="display:inline">
                    
                         <option selected="selected" value="1">&lt;KwikTag&gt;</option>
                            
                </select>


Not sure why it's not displaying it...?

Comment: @Michael Shimmins, it was due to us not running .net 4. We're still on 3.5.